# A question about function call and evaluation in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Hey there,
I have a probably straight-forward question about the following problem:

I have a function

```
double afunction(double *myarray)
{   
    double ret = 1.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        ret *= myarray[i]*myarray[i];
    return ret;
}
```

Now I want to modify it so that I pass two new parameters: `int index` describing which index of `myarray` to change like the following: `myarray[ index ] = *add;`. This would be the following:

```
double afunction(double *myarray, int index, double *add)
{   
    myarray[ index ] += *add;
    double ret = 1.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        ret *= myarray[i]*myarray[i];
    return ret;
}
```

The problem is: I **don't want to modify** the array `myrray` and I **don't want to create a new array** for this because of memory-regards (this will later be computed on the GPU and there I couldn't allocate a whole new array in a kernel function anyway.
Easy solution to this?
Thanks!

**EDIT**
Sorry, I mistyped something. Instead `myarray[ index ] = *add;` I meant to say `myarray[ index ] += *add;`

**EDIT2**
Example of a bigger function which could later on easily be extended to about 50 different return-cases. So to have the if-statement to modify the certain value `myarray[index]` with adding `*add` in each return-case is pretty ugly :(

```
double afunction(double *myarray, int funcIndex, int indexAdd, double *add)
{   
    myarray[ indexAdd ] += *add;

    if(funcIndex >= 1 && funcIndex <= 4)
        return myarray[1]*myarray[1]*myarray[2];

    switch(funcIndex)
    {
        case 5:
            return sin(myarray[3]) * cos(myarray[1]);
        case 6:
            double ret = exp(myarray[1]);
            for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                ret *= (myarray[ i ]-myarray[ 5-i ]);
            return ret;
        case 7:
            double ret = 0.0;
            for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
                ret += myarray[ i ];
            return ret;
    }

    return 0.0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double afunction(double *myarray, int index, double *add)
{   
    double ret = (*add) * (*add);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        if( i != index )
            ret *= myarray[i]*myarray[i];
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
double ret = 1.0;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    if (index == i)
        ret *= (*add) * (*add);
    else
        ret *= myarray[i]*myarray[i];
```

or:

```
double ret = (*add) * (*add);
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    ret *= myarray[i]*myarray[i];

ret /= myarray[index] * myarray[index];
```

Which isn't 100% equivalent though since you're using floating point numbers.

**EDIT:** Ok, saw that you edited the original question. One alternative which might be acceptable would be to do:

```
myarray[ indexAdd ] -= *add;
```

after you're done with the rest of the calculations. Again there's no guarantee that `myarray[indexAdd]` will return to *exactly* it's old value.

or even better, save the old value at the top of the function and then restore it:

```
float old = myarray[ indexAdd ];
myarray[ indexAdd ] += *add;
//do work
myarray[ indexAdd ] = old;
```

Comment: It may work fine and again it may not, it all depends on the input to the function.

Comment: Exactly. And this "depends on" is what scares me.

Comment: All floating point functions are sensitive to the input though, even the original function (without the `*add` stuff) will return different values if you shuffle the order of the elements in `myarray`.

Comment: Okay thanks you both. You're right and I got the point. The problem rather is: The function could quite simple look bloated and not as easy as stated above (I inserted an example). Surely I could insert the statement in each case, but this would really look ugly. So I bet there's probably no way of not copying the array and modify the value, except for really imeplementing in each case the if-statement to modify **the ONE** value :(

Comment: Okay thanks again. The last solution I feel would be the 'coolest' since it is easy to implement, but as I want to use it later in a multithreaded environment, this isn't possible either :(

Comment: Okay what I want to do is calculating the derivative matrix: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant -> So each thread needs to calculate a certain mathematical function with the index 1..m. To calculate the derivative I use the input array x (imagine it as the input vector of coordinates (size n)) and do: (f_m(x2)-f_m(x))/h whereas x2 is the original array with the value `h` added to the n-th coordinate.

Comment: Another thread calculates the derivative of the same function f_m (or could also of another function of the functionvector) but builds the derivative about another coordinate and thus needs to modify the 'original' coordinates by adding `h` to another coordinate. That's why each thread needs a copy of the 'original' point to modify it (adding `h` to ONE of the coordinates) and calculating of one of the functions 1..m of the functionvector

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible solutions:

The obvious:

```
double
aFunction( double* array, int index, double add )
{
    double result = 1.0;
    for ( int i = 0; i != 4; ++ i ) {
        double tmp = array[i];
        if ( i == index ) {
            tmp += add;
        }
        result *= tmp * tmp;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Possibly quicker (no if in the loop), but with possibly different
results:

```
double
aFunction( double* array, int index, double add )
{
    double result = 1.0;
    for ( int = 0; i != 4; ++ i ) {
        result *= array[i] * array[i];
    }
    //  Since we multiplied by array[i]^2, when we should
    //  have multipied by (array[i] + add)^2...
    result *= 2 * array[index] * add + add * add;
    return result;
}
```

I've my doubts as to whether this one is worth bothering with for an
array of four elements: four `if`s are likely no more expensive than the
final additional calculation.  For longer arrays, however, it might be
worth considering.

Finally, more for reference, since it is really ugly, and only works in
a single threaded environment:

```
double
aFunction( double* array, int index, double add )
{
    array[index] += add;
    double result = 1.0;
    for ( int i = 0; i != 4; ++ i ) {
        result *= array[i] * array[i];
    }
    array[index] -= add;
    return result;
}
```

Depending on the actual hardware and compiler optimizations, this could
be the quickest.  (But again, for just four elements, it's far from
certain.)

Two other comments concerning the code: if you're not going to modify
`array`, you should probably pass it as a `double const*` (which
eliminates the last possibility above), and since all you do is read
a single value, there's really no point in passing `add` as a pointer;
in my code above, I've passed it by value.